# URL redirect based on GET params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I would like to make URLs on my website a bit nicer.

Currently, single product pages are in form of:

`www.mywebsite.com/details.php?id=1`

and I would like those to be more like

`www.mywebsite.com/name-of-the-product?id=1`

where id=1 is changeable and it will be id of specific product.

So I would like to redirect all new links to old page named `details.php`, passing id to it.

I searched through some answers, but all of those are for predefined and specific GET params, I would like this to be more general, for all products on website.

**updated**

Thanks everyone for help! It looks like I misleaded you. I have numerous pages on website. And I want to change routes only for this one (single product pages, so that those particular routes, look nicer).
Right now, only @samurai 's answer does redirecting, but it redirect's also every other page. That's why I was thinking to add some specific GET param (or something like that), to tell .htaccess 'hey, only redirect pages like this to details.php'.
Is it possible to do it like that?

Comment: if you have already "name-of-the-product" why do you need product_id in your URL?

Maybe you need URL like this: www.mywebsite.com/product/1 where 1 is your product ID?

Comment: could be that I'm missing something. I was thinking it would be easier to fetch it by id, than to convert url slug back to product name. so it would be like: nike-air-max, and in my db it's Nike Air Max, etc

Comment: and I thought it would be easier to fetch URL (in .htaccess), if it has something specific (like id=?) in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal rewrite would look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!details\.php)[^/]+/?$ details.php [L]
```

The query string is automatically carried over. The `(?details\.php)` part is a negative look-ahead. It prevents details.php from matching this rule, as this would cause an infinite loop. Please note that you should:

- Check in details.php if an id is supplied. If it isn't supplied, you should do your database-magic to obtain this id, then redirect the client in php

  ```
  if( empty( $_GET['id'] ) ) {
    $id = getIdByName( $name );
    header( "Location: {$name}?id={$id}", 301 );
    exit();
  }
  ```
- Check if details.php is not requested directly. You cannot summon the product name from thin air in .htaccess, so you need to do this in your php script

  ```
  if( empty( $name ) || $name == "details.php" ) {
    $name = getNameById( $id );
    header( "Location: {$name}?id={$id}", 301 );
    exit();
  }
  ```

Comment: hey @Sumurai8, I tried it, but it redirects all pages, to details. php. Please check my updated question.

Comment: The way this is usually countered, is by adding a common prefix (sort-of what lolbas suggested). If all products are in the form `product/product-name?id=123`, you can match it with `RewriteRule ^product/[^/]+/?$ details.php [L]`. Alternatively exclude all pages you don't want to match in the negative look-ahead, but this gets messy real fast!

Comment: and one last question regarding this, sorry I'm a total noob for this. css, js and other assets are now fetched from `/product` instead from root `/` for this page. Can it be fixed as well?

Comment: Here's how my .htaccess looks like right now: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^product/[^/]+/?$ details.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: You are using relative urls for your css and js, so it takes the url that appears in the address bar and tries to find the css and js files relative to that. Obviously it won't find them there. Either make those urls absolute or use `<base href="/">` in the head of your html page.

Comment: yes, well the last question was probably the dumbest of all today :) thanks again, it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Why to keep id in url when it will show product name?
Anyway, what you can do is get product name from database based on supplied id, head page to desired url and add some .htaccess magic

UPD: Lets take Nike Air Max as an example. user tries to access next url: `www.mywebsite.com/?id=1`, while in your database Air Maxes assosiated with id=1. Piece of php code of ur page:

```
$id = intval( $_GET['id'], 10 );
$product_name = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT item_name FROM products WHERE id = $id"));
$altered_name = str_replace(' ', '-', $product_name);
header('Location: /?id=1&product_name='.$altered_name);
```

And now some .htaccess magic

```
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)$ /?id=1&product_name=$1 [L]
```

As a result, url will be  `www.website.com/product/nike-air-maxes`

Comment: yes, well that .htaccess magic is the part I'm interested in :)

Comment: thanks for the comment and help. I'll upvote your answer, I wish I could give points for both of your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Create an .htaccess file and put those lines in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
# URL rewriting rules
RewriteRule ^([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$ details.php?id=$2 [L,E]
```

and your url should be : `www.mywebsite.com/name-of-the-product/1`

or

```
RewriteRule ^([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$ details.php [L,E]
```

to have a url like this : `www.mywebsite.com/name-of-the-product?id=1`

Comment: thanks, I tried, but could't get it to work, it's like it's ignoring rule completely. Please see my updated question.